# Connect to SQLite .db file served on localhost using http-server (node.js) from my VS C# project?

Tags: c#, node.js, sqlite, localhost, httpserver

Initially I developed my project by putting the .db file within the project folder. Now I want to host the database on localhost so I put the db file on a new folder and started a http-server using node.js on localhost:8080. To start the server I used this command on node.js command line `C:\Users\Me\aswserver>http-server .`
aswserver folder contains only aswDB.db.

On my C# project until now I used the connection string

`<connectionStrings>   <addname="SQLite"connectionString="DataSource=.\aswDB.db;Version=3;"providerName="System.Data.SQLClient"/>
</connectionStrings>`

and included the db file to project(Build Action: Content and Copy to output if newer).
After hosting the db on localhost I tried this connection string

`<connectionStrings>
    <add name="SQLite" connectionString="Data Source=localhost:8080/aswDB.db;Version=3;" providerName="System.Data.SQLClient" />
  </connectionStrings>`

Now when I try to connect to the db from the project I get Exception saying "The given path's format is not supported". How do I set up the connection so that any change I make to the db stays in aswDB.db on the server? (I plan to connect it to a Xamarin.android app too)

Comment: That's not how SQLite works - you need a local file on your file system to open and write files to. When you host a file through a HTTP server you will be constantly downloading a _new copy_ of the file each time, which doesn't make sense for what you're trying to do. If you need to have a distributed database look into MySQL, Postgres, MS SQL, etc, anything that you install and runs as a stand-alone service which you connect to over ports.

Comment: @gunr2171 so there's no way to do what I'm trying to do using sqlite?

Comment: As mentioned in there earlier comments, If you wish to share the database between multiple applications, you should consider using server based DB such as MySQL, MSSql, Postgres etc. MySql community version is free to use